# Sitecore 10.2 Horizon Internal Server Error

Tags: installation, horizon

After installing `Sitecore 10.2 Horizon` I got this error.

[image]

I compared this with `Sitecore 10.1 Horizn web.config` and found a change for `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"`. Here is the section

```
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

Kindly update if I need to set up something else to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Need to install [Asp.Net Core Runtime 2.2 Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.2)

And register it manually like this.

[image]